# The IO operation at logical block was retried and CRC errors in S.M.A.R.T

Tags: windows-10, ssd, sata, event-viewer, crc

I have a Samsung 850 Evo (250GB) SSD since December 2016 (2+years). In February this year my system started to lag and while digging in Event Viewer I saw Event 153 + CRC error count in SMART go up. In the end I changed SATA cable and port on my motherboard and for a month everything was good, no more warnings in Event Viewer and CRC error count in SMART didn't change.
I also reinstalled Windows after this.

Today, while booting, my system lagged unusually, so I opened Event Viewer and found out that the issue has returned. I had few Warnings (Event 153) since 1 March, but a lot of them yesterday and today. I change SATA cable and port again and for now I see no new warnings in Event Viewer and CRC error count in SMART stays unchanged.

But what could be the issue here? Why the problem goes away when I change port and cable but then returns?

OS: Windows 10 (version - 1809, build - 17763.379)

Text of warning in Event Viewer:
The IO operation at logical block address 0xa7afa88 for Disk 0 (PDO name: \Device\0000003c) was retried.

S.M.A.R.T. from Samsung Magician: [on imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2p70Y.png).

Motherboard: Asus Z97-K

Driver tab in SSD properties:

- Driver Provider: Microsoft
- Driver Date: 21-Jun-06
- Driver Version: 10.0.17763.1

Actually every driver for my motherboard (except for the sound) is from Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ultra DMA CRC error count indicates problems with the transfer of data between
the host and the disk. They can't be caused by software, and usually they don't
indicate a problem with the disk itself.

You could try a high-quality SATA cable, but know that it is not only caused
by the cable, and may also indicate a problem with the 
SATA controller on the motherboard.

If the computer is still under warranty, I recommend using it.
If not, and a better SATA cable does not help, a repair-shop is indicated
(get a quote before starting).

Comment: Right now I'm thinking between motherboard controller and controller in ssd. I have 2 other drives (older SSD and HDD) and they don't show any problems. Plus I can't think of why changing port+cable fixed it before (even if for a month), and fixed it now (I hope permanently)

Comment: The reason might be a better cable. You are right about two controllers, one on each side, and it might be that one of them is a bit marginal.

Answer (score 1):

Finally fixed this warning on my machine with new SATA cable. Symptoms include: warnings in windows event viewer, slow HDD/SSD response, and 100% load. Switched port and SATA cable, and everything works again. Windows 10 x64, Hynix SSD 128GB. For me it was a purely hardware issue.